# invalid write/read of size 1 and XX bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm having these issues in my code and I search for solutions here in StackOverflow and in another site but I can't understand why this is happening.

I need to implement a hash table and I will post here the functions of my code that I'm having issues and signalize where occur.

**OBS: When I try to close the file opened in the LOAD function, I receive an error:

```
 Munmap_chunk: invalid pointer
```

this happens when the word is *pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis***

```
// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(word); i++) ****Invalid read of size 1**
    {
        sum = (sum + (i * tolower(word[i]))); ****Invalid read of size 1**
    }

    if (sum > N)
    {
        sum = sum % strlen(word);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO

    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");****552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 5**
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open this file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            table[i] = NULL;
        }

        char *word1 = malloc(sizeof(LENGTH + 1));

        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word1) != EOF)****Invalid write of size 1**
        {

            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL)
            {
                free(n);
                return 1;
            }

            strcpy(n->word, word1);****Invalid read of size 1**
            n->next = NULL;

            unsigned int index = hash(word1);

            if (table[index] == NULL)
            {
                table[index] = n;
            }
            else
            {
                n->next = table[index];
                table[index] = n;
            }
        }

        free(word1);
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO

    int count = 0;
    node *cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cursor->next = NULL;
                                 ****56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 5**
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        if (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            cursor = table[i];

            while (cursor != NULL)
            {
                count++;
                cursor = cursor->next;
            }
        }
    }

    free(cursor);
    return count;
}
```

```
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO

    int count = size();
    int count1 = 0;
    node *cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cursor->next = NULL;****56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 5**
    tmp->next = NULL;****56 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 5**

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            cursor = table[i];

            while (cursor != NULL)
            {
                tmp = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->next;
                free(tmp);
                count1++;
            }
        }
    }

    free(cursor);
    if (count1 == count)
        {
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(LENGTH + 1)` is wrong.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(word); i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)`

Comment: In `unsigned int size(void)` you allocate memory for `cursor` and if the loop iterates, it gets overwritten and so it can never be `free`d. It is unclear what you *do* `free` though.

Comment: `FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");` - there is no corresponding `fclose()`

Comment: There are too many useless blank lines in your code. Blank lines are useful, but abusing them is not.

Comment: Aside: there is too much white-space in the code. While that is better than cramped code devoid of spacing, double-spaced code is still hard to read (it overflows the panel). The *right* amount of spacing is good!

Comment: Aside: `while (fscanf(file, "%s", word1) != EOF)` would be better as `while (fscanf(file, "%s", word1) == 1)`

Comment: A [mcve] would help.  The easiest way for someone to help you find bugs in your code is if they can compile, run and test your program.  Without a complete program (including `main` function, etc) they can't do that.  But it is also important to strip down your program first, removing all the code that isn't related to the bug, to minimize the anount of code that someone has to wade through to help.